# Swapping binary trees in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, swap

This is exercise 3.5 from *Learn Prolog Now*. They put it before explaining lists so I need a procedure that doesn't involve lists.

The task is to swap the leaves of nested binary trees. If the query is

```
swap(tree(tree(leaf(1), leaf(2)), leaf(4)), T).
```

the answer should be

```
T = (tree(leaf(4), tree(leaf(2), leaf(1))).
```

With

```
swap((X, Y), (Y, X)).

swap(tree(X, Y), T) :- 
   swap((X, Y), (Y, X)), 
   T = (Y, X).
```

I get

```
T = (leaf(4), tree(leaf(1), leaf(2))).
```

As you see the `leaf(1)` and `leaf(2)` didn't get swapped. I want some hints or even your procedure and it should work with any depth of the nodes. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You have a base case swap a leaf, and a general case swap a tree!
For a leaf, nothing to do :

```
swap(leaf(X), leaf(X)).
```

When you swap a tree, you must swap its leaves too, so

```
swap(tree(X,Y), tree(Y1,X1)) :-
    swap(X,X1),
    swap(Y,Y1).
```